# Language switcher in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, multilingual

I'm looking for a simple plugin for WordPress to be able to switch the language on the front-end.
I tried many plugins no one worked. I just need to prefix my page path with something like **/en/my_page**  and transform it to **/fr/my_page** when I select French as the current language for instance.

Comment: You can try a session based language configuration instead of a prefix

Comment: What do you mean by session based language configuration? In either case, I still need a widget in the front-end to allow to end user to switch the language.

Comment: You can persist the language configuration in the session, for example: `$_SESSION['language'] = 'en-us';` and display your theme according to the value in $_SESSION['language']

Answer (score 0):

I also have spent in the past quite a lot of time looking for a plugin to create sites in various languages.

The only plugin I would recommend is Qtranslate https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/
Its very simple, and easy to customize the front-end template using shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a free plugin for that purpose here:

https://code.recuweb.com/get/language-switcher/

It has been reviewed and hosted by Wordpress here:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/language-switcher/

Language Switcher allows you to map urls of alternative languages for Post Types and Taxonomies. Additionally it allows you to filter archive pages by language.

To prefix your pages with the language code I recommend you to follow these steps:

1. create a main page with slug **en** and another one with slug **fr**.
2. set **my_page** with parent page **en** and **ma_page** with parent page **fr**.
3. map the urls of the translations in **my_page** and **ma_page**
4. add the shortcode `[language-switcher]` to allow readers to jump from one page to another